# Parse.com Xamarin giving "Input JSON Invalid" on initialize

Tags: c#, android, parse-platform, xamarin

I have an Android application I'm building in Xamarin with the Parse API. Earlier, this code was running fine but recently for seemingly no reason I've started having the app crash whenever Parse tries to initialize with a Json error. I have these two lines of code:
    `ParseClient.Initialize ("mykey", "mydotnetkey");
    ParseFacebookUtils.Initialize ("716545131791857");`

The top one will throw the following exception, and if it's commented out then the bottom one does the same thing. I tried updating my Parse component and no help.

```
$exception  {System.ArgumentException: Input JSON was invalid.
  at Parse.Internal.Json.Parse (System.String input) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Parse.ParseClient.DeserializeJsonString (System.String jsonData) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Parse.PlatformHooks+SettingsWrapper..ctor (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Parse.PlatformHooks.b__24 () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Lazy`1[Parse.PlatformHooks+SettingsWrapper].InitValue () [0x00000] in :0 }    System.ArgumentException
```

Comment: It's trying to read a file with JSON content, maybe it got corrupted or just does not exist. Try to fully uninstall the app from your device and reinstall it again.

Comment: That seemed to help it, thanks

Comment: @Gusman thank you, been looking for this for an hour. If you made it a proper answer I'd vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is from the user Gusman, who gave it in a comment to the question.

It has saved me SO much time that it really ought to be an accepted answer, but it looks like Gusman hasn't been active here since 2016.

Here it is:

> It's trying to read a file with JSON content, maybe it got corrupted
> or just does not exist. Try to fully uninstall the app from your
> device and reinstall it again.

I hope it helps others in as drastic a way as it has me. Please vote for this answer, not for my sake, but for the sake of others looking for this information.